# How to open different excel sheets using a class python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, amazon-s3

So I am pretty new to classes but I am trying to write one that opens a excel file in a dataframe then extracts some information from it then moves on to the next excel file and does the same. The name of each file is the same with a different number on the end and this cannot be changed - the numbers are not consistent.

I have tried this code:

```
 class Systems:

    def __init__(self, survey_number):
        self.survey_number = survey_number
        self.file_name = 's3://misc/survey' + survey_number + '.xlsx'

    def readfile(self):
        self.df = pd.read_excel(self.file_name, sheet_name='Results')

 survey_1 = Systems('026')

 survey_1.df
```

I thought this should being up the dataframe for the first input then I could do the same with the other files names however I am getting error:

```
AttributeError: Systems instance has no attribute 'df'
```

I have not included a sample of that data as I don't think it is needed for this? Let me know if it is.
I will be adding more functions to the class when it is working but think this step needs resolving first and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks!

EDIT - I believe the problem is trying to read the file using the '...' + variable + '...' method - is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Systems:
def __init__(self, survey_number):
    self.file_name = 'yourpath' + survey_number + '.xlsx'
    self.df = pd.read_excel(self.file_name, sheet_name='Results')
```

and then

```
a = Systems('123')
```

a has then a property call df which is what you are looking for.

```
a.df
```

Comment: Thanks but this has not fixed the issue, still the same

Comment: I have updated the answer and it works for me. You might need to install s3fs via pip

Comment: perfect that works thanks! Do you know why it works under the __init__ function and not under the new function I tried to add?

Comment: I removed the second function because it was not really necessary, to make it work with a different function you would first have call a = Systems('123') and then a.readfile(), which is unecessary code